# create a pyspark dataframe from a python dictionary with one column as np.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to create a pyspark dataframe from a python dictionary with one column as np.narray.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
d = {1: np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 2), 20: np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 2)}
df = spark.createDataFrame(d.items(), ['id', 'val']).cache() # error: TypeError: not supported type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
display(df)
```

I have also tried to convert the ndarray to list but it still does not work.

How to create a dataframe with this kind of array ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark cannot infer the data type for np.float64 objects. You need to convert them to Python floats:

```
d = {1: [float(i) for i in np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 2)],
     20: [float(i) for i in np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 2)]
    }
```